# How do i convert a nested for loop into a nested for each loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, linked-list

So I have this nested for loop and I am struggling to convert it into a nested for each loop.

`private LinkedList<Integer> Lis[] = new LinkedList[4];`

```
   public ArrayList<Integer> abc(int x) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Lis[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        }
        ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j<3; j++) {
               if (Lis[i].get(j) == x){
                  list1.add(i);
               }
            }
        }
        return list1;
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you're struggling because the for each loop isn't the right solution.

Comment: @FredLarson So if I do Lis[1].add(1),Lis[1].add(3),Lis[1].add(2)...and then I call the method abc(2). It gives me index out of bounds error. I get it that it gives me the error because I dont have anything for Lis[2]. So I am not sure what to exactly do here and thought a for each might work.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve with this function?  Just to be sure, you know that every call to abc will clobber the contents of Lis[], correct?